# continuous interest: how is it calculated?

Tags: limits, functions

I got this problem:

A man wants to buy a car in 5 years. the car will cost ${$15000}$ and he will invest the money now. He has 2 options: compound interest at 3% interest compounded daily or continuous interest for 2.5%. how much will he have to invest for each? which will he have to invest less to get there?

so i started with this formula of compound interest:

$$ \text{P}\left(1+\left(\frac{\text{I}}{\text{n}}\right)\right)^{\text{Yn}}=A
\Rightarrow
\left( \frac{\text{A}}{1+\left(\frac{\text{I}}{\text{n}}\right)}\right)^{\text{Yn}}=P\\
\begin{align}
\text{P}&=\text{Principal Amt./Start amount}\\
\text{I}&=\text{Interest}\\
\text{Y}&=\text{Years}\\
\text{n}&=\text{periods in year}\\
\text{A}&=\text{Total amount}
\end{align}
$$

I substitute the values as so:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{P}&=\text{???}\\
\text{I}&=0.03\\
\text{Y}&=5\text{Years}\\
\text{n}&=365\\
\text{A}&=15000\\
\end{align}
$$

then i plug these variables into the equation, as so:

$$
\begin{align}
P&=\left( \frac{\text{A}}{1+\left(\frac{\text{I}}{\text{n}}\right)^{\text{Yn}}}\right)\\
&=\left( \frac{15000}{1+\left(\frac{0.03}{365}\right)^{5\times 365}}\right)\\
&=\left( \frac{15000}{\left(1+0.00008219\right)^{5\times 365}}\right)\\
&=\left( \frac{15000}{\left(1.00008219\right)^{1825}}\right)\\
&=\left( \frac{15000}{1.1618233}\right)\\
&\approx $12910.74 \pm $0.10
\end{align}
$$

so the man will have to pay ${$12910.74}$ to get 15000 by the end of 5 years to get the car.

**ON TO THE CONTINUOUS INTEREST!!**

So for continuous interest, to find it, you first have to calculate the continuity, which I assume is found using n to a very high number. So i used the limit expression:

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}
$$

I used $n$ to progressively higher powers and got the following:

$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{1}{1}\right)^{1}&=2\\
\left(1+\frac{1}{10}\right)^{10}&=2.5937424601000000000000000000000\\
\left(1+\frac{1}{100}\right)^{100}&=2.7048138294215260932671947108075\\
\left(1+\frac{1}{1000}\right)^{1000}&=2.7169239322358924573830881219476\\
\left(1+\frac{1}{10000}\right)^{10000}&=2.7181459268252248640376646749131\\
\left(1+\frac{1}{1000000000}\right)^{1000000000}&=2.7182818270999043223766440238603\\
\end{align}
$$

So this leads to an interesting answer:

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}=e
$$

so i substituted it into the continuous formula to

$$ 
 \text{P}\left(e\text{I}\right)^{\text{Y}}=A
\Rightarrow
\left( \frac{\text{A}}{1+\left(e\text{I}\right)}\right)^{\text{Y}}=P\\
\begin{align}
\text{P}&=\text{Principal Amt./Start amount}\\
\text{I}&=\text{Interest}\\
\text{Y}&=\text{Years}\\
\text{n}&=\text{periods in year}\\
\text{A}&=\text{Total amount}
\end{align}
$$

I substitute the values as so:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{P}&=\text{???}\\
\text{I}&=0.025\\
e&=\text{Euler's Number}\\
\text{Y}&=5\text{Years}\\
\text{A}&=15000\\
\end{align}
$$

(This is about the time my formulas go **KA-BLEWY**) I substituted the varibles in:

$$
\begin{align}
P&=\left( \frac{\text{A}}{1+\left(e\text{I}\right)}\right)\\
&= \frac{\text{15000}}{1+0.06795704571147613088400718678382}\\
&= \frac{\text{15000}}{1.06795704571147613088400718678382}\\
&= $14045.51 \pm $0.15\\
\end{align}
$$

**BUT** there is a problem: I plugged it into a [calculator](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/compound-interest-calculator.php) and i got $P = $ 13,237.45$, which does **NOT** equate to my answer. I asked my equally-genius friend and he didn't know, either. what am i doing wrong???

Comment: I'm not totally understanding what you're doing but the correct form for continuously compounding interest is $A = P e^{iY}$ in your framework. This should lead you to the correct answer.

Comment: @Gregory put this in the answer, then! i'll check it in a few minutes

Comment: N.B. the RHS of your first implication is wrong: only the denominator is raised to the $Yn$ power, not the whole fraction.

Comment: that's what i'm going at. if i did it that way, i'd get yelled at by everyone saying i put something incorrect

Comment: Your formulas are wrong in various places (as I tried to point out before).  For example, you say $P(eI)^Y= A \Rightarrow P = (A / (1 + eI))^Y$: that's absolutely false - the formula on the RHS *does not follow* from the formula on the LHS. Please talk to your teacher about this: it will take much less time for him or her to explain than for you to type in wrong formulas into this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the formula:
$$A = P \left(1+ \frac{r}{n}\right)^{nt}$$

Define $k = \dfrac{n}{r}$ and we can reorganize the expression:

$$A = P \left(1+ \frac{r}{n}\right)^{nt} = P \left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)^{krt}= P \left(\left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)^k \right)^{rt}$$

As $n \to \infty$, so does $k$, which means the inner piece $\left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)^k$ goes to $e$, as you noticed, which leads to the result:

$$A = Pe^{rt}$$

Comment: that's why!!! i was wondering why...

Answer (score 1):

The correct form should be $A = Pe^{iY}$, that seems to be the only mistake.